# Can an amplifier charge itself?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, feedback

My friend asked me this question and I had no answer.

Here is what is proposed :

An amplifier is fed a current of, say 1 Ampere. Let's say it amplifies it to 100 Amperes. The output is so designed with parallel resistances that one of the branches draws 1 Ampere and the other, 99 Amperes.

The 1 Ampere is fed back to the amplifier and is used to power it.

I know a little current will be lost each time so it can't go on forever. But what if the amplifier used five amperes to charge itself?

Is this a feasible idea? Can it happen?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you had no answer to that question, you were absolutely right.

Answer (score 4):

Without a separate power source, no.

You cannot create energy out of nothing. Your device that takes 1A as input and provides 100A as output can work one of two ways:

1. It can work as a transformer, reducing the output voltage so the power stays the same. Power supplies do this - take, for example, 230V/1A and provide, for example, 23V/10A.
2. It can use a separate power source to provide the output power. Audio amplifiers work this way - take low power signal AND power from the mains or a battery and provide the output.

In both cases, the total power output from the device is ideally the same as the total power input to it. In reality, the device itself wastes some power as heat and you end up with the total output electrical power less than the total input power. The difference is the heat power dissipated in the device.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. So, power is the parameter that has to be constant?

Comment: Yes. It's the same thing as conservation of energy.